# Is this a cleft sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions

Is this a cleft sentence or a "preparatory it"?

> It was my tablet which I didn't realize had fallen off the bed and on the floor.

Is it correct?

I think it should leave out the structure "I didn't realize."

Comment: You **could** leave out “I didn’t realize.” But consider this context, “Groping around on the floor in the dark, I discovered something surprising and couldn’t figure out what was going on.” Then the speaker might like to explain not only what the unexpected shape on the floor was, but also why the discovery had been so surprising.”

Comment: What is a cleft sentence? What is a preparatory it? EL&U expects a little research (some definitions you're working with) so that potential answers know where the starting point is.

Comment: Can you provide the context? As PaulTanenbaum says, it can be viewed in a number of different ways, depending on whether "it" refers to something already mentioned or not. And I've no idea why you want to leave out "I didn't realise": this could change the whole meaning of the sentence - saying "X happened" and "I didn't realise that X happened" are different statements. "I didn't realise" is sometimes used parenthetically if it's not the main focus of the sentence ("and by the way I didn't know this at the time") but can function as the main/matrix clause.

Comment: Your basic question is a grammatical one about clefts, but your question about the acceptability of "I didn't realize" is a semantic one.

Comment: **If** _tablet_ is stressed, **and** the entire clause following it is flattened in tone, then this could be considered an _it_-cleft. But it'd hafta be a strange situation -- this requires several available choices for what "I didn't realize had fallen off the bed and on the floor", possibly including one previous incorrect one in a discourse that's being corrected by the cleft. That's unlikely. My first reaction is that it's referential.